# "Pivot" a table using Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

(Disclaimer: I'm very new to Hadoop and Java)

As an input, have a table with a simple key-value structure:

```
key1  value1
key2  value2
key3  value3
key2  value4
key1  value5
key1  value6
```

As an output, I would like to collect all values that belong to the particular key, for each key, so something like this:

```
key1, value1 value5 value6
key2, value2 value4
key3, value3
```

Here is my mapper:

```
public class WordMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

 @Override
 public void map(Object key, Text value,
   Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String[] fields = value.toString().split("\\t", -1); 
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; ++i) {
        if ("".equals(fields[i])) fields[i] = null;
    }
    List<String> fields_list = Arrays.asList(fields);
    Text textKey = new Text(fields_list.get(0));
    Text textValue = new Text(fields_list.get(1));
    context.write(textKey,textValue);
    }
 }
```

And here is the reducer:

```
public class SumReducer extends Reducer<Text, TextArrayWritable, Text, TextArrayWritable> {
    private TextArrayWritable valuesTotal = new TextArrayWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<Text> values_list = new ArrayList<Text>();

        for (Text value : values) {
             values_list.add(value);
    }
        Text[] values_arr = new Text[values_list.size()];
        values_arr = values_list.toArray(values_arr);

         valuesTotal.setFields(values_arr);
         context.write(key, valuesTotal);
}
}
```

For some reason I'm unable to get any output from my program. It just terminates, leaving nothing in the output folder. What is my problem here?

(I use Hadoop 2.2.0 and Eclipse + hadoop plugin. WordCount example runs without problems.)

Comment: How does your TextArrayWritable class look like?

Comment: I solved the problem and get rid of the class as it's not really needed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. After I enabled logging, it becomes clear that my data includes rows where value were missing in the 4rd column, so I added the null check `if (fields[4] != null)` and it worked. Also I get rid of array to list convertion and usage of TextArrayWritable custom class

Mapper:

```
@Override
 public void map(Object key, Text value,
   Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String[] fields = value.toString().split("\\t", -1); 
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; ++i) {
        if ("".equals(fields[i])) fields[i] = null;
    }
    if (fields[4] != null) {
    System.out.println(fields[0]);
    System.out.println(fields[4]);
    context.write(new Text(fields[0]),new Text(fields[4]));
    }
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
public class SongsReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> { 
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        boolean first = true;
        StringBuilder songs = new StringBuilder();;
        for (Text val : values){
              if (!first)
                songs.append(",");
              first=false;
              songs.append(val.toString());
            }

        context.write(key, new Text(songs.toString()));
}
}
```